Free scalar field deriving Ehrenfest using the path integral
In his lecture notes on String theory, David Tong derives Ehrenfest theorem using the path integral:
$$S = \frac{1}{4\pi \alpha'}\int d^2\sigma\ \partial_\alpha X\  \partial^\alpha X\tag{4.19}$$
$$ 0 = \int DX \frac{\delta}{\delta X(\sigma)} e^{-S} =  \int DX \ e^{-S} \left[\frac{1}{2\pi \alpha'} \partial^2 X(\sigma)\right].\tag{p.77}$$
How to do this calculation? When I did it myself, I tried something with partial integration, but got instead:
$$\int DX \frac{\delta}{\delta X(\sigma)} e^{-S} = \int DX \ e^{-S} \left[\color{Red}{\int d^2\sigma}\  \frac{1}{2\pi \alpha'} \partial^2 X(\sigma)\right].$$
Also, how is the functional derivative defined here? (In the past I put some effort into understanding the functional derivative, but I found several definitions, which makes it a rather confusing concept.)

Linked, and also.

Related: Why does the integral symbol disappear when applying a functional derivative? and links therein.

Dozens of questions on this site remind you that
$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta X(\tau)}~\int\!\! d^2\sigma ~ \partial_\alpha X(\sigma)  \partial^\alpha X(\sigma) =-2\partial^2 X(\tau) .$$
Crudely, you may use $\frac{\delta X(\sigma)}{\delta X(\tau)}= \delta (\tau-\sigma)$.
